# Pipe output of journalctl -f into file but with limited file size

Tags: logging, systemd, journal

I would like to pipe `journalctl -f -o json` into file but don't size gets very big after some time? Can I set it somehow to rotate?

Command:

```
journalctl -f -o json>> /tmp/myFile &
```

Lets say that after reaching size of 10 MB or after reaching 2000 lines I would like to rotate log.

Is there some simple command to do that or it require shell/python script running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Rotatelogs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html) (part of Apache Webserver distribution) is what you are searching for. It's a versatile tool, not limited to webserver logfiles:

```sh
journalctl -f -o json | rotatelogs "journal-%c".json 10M
```